# Swift missing constraints

Tags: swift, xcode

I have stacked a view has a stack of labels and a `TableView` in single stack view (as shown in the picture below), however it's giving me a constraints for the x and y position of the two views inside the main stack view. I tried adding constraints for both views but it didn't work.

[Stack View Constraints error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKE6f.png)

Comment: @fakegirlfriends I am new to this whole thing, first I need to understand the basics and then I'll switch to programmatic, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Try playing around with stack's alignment and distribution. Also, did you set constraints for the stack itself?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have constraints for the stack view itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could click this blue icon to see your layout constraints(you should check both Horizon and Vertical).
[image]

Also, if your constraint has problems, you can see there is a red arrow, click it to see the error message.
[image]